# Pandas: Unexpected behavior of Series.dt

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Why does changes to the datetime properties of a series, accessed through Series.dt, not show up when applying a formatter to the series, at which point it all reverts to utc?

Consider the following code sample (whose purpose is to show a time series in british summer time):

```
import pandas as pd
import logging
import pytz
from pytz import timezone

date_format_string = "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M"

def convert_datetime(x) :
    return x.strftime(date_format_string)

def longer_convert(x, tz = timezone('Europe/London')) :
    return convert_datetime(pytz.utc.localize(x).astimezone(tz))


if __name__=="__main__" :
    rng = pd.date_range('6/6/2011', periods=6, freq='H')
    rng2 = pd.date_range('6/6/2011', periods=6, freq='D')

    series = pd.Series(data=rng, index=rng2)
    series.name = "Original"

    converted_series = series.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/London')
    converted_series.name = "Converted"

    formatted_series = converted_series.apply(convert_datetime)
    formatted_series.name = "Formatted"

    longer_converted = series.apply(longer_convert)
    longer_converted.name = "Using pytz"

    df=pd.concat([series,converted_series,formatted_series, longer_converted], axis=1)
    print df
```

Output :

[image]

Although the series "Converted" using dt.localise prints correctly, applying the string format operator in Formatted causes the times to revert to UTC times. I expected this to behave like the column "Using pytz" and output the column format as local time in its new timezone. Is this a bug or is there some reason for this oddity?

Even more oddly :

```
dt = df.iloc[3].get_value("Converted")
print dt
print convert_datetime(dt)
```

Correctly prints 04:00+1:00 and 04:00 so why does the apply behave differently Or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it is a known bug as of pandas 18.0 that apply will strip off the timezone properties applyed through series.dt.localize

A working solution is to do

```
converted_series.dt.strftime(date_format_string)
```

rather than use apply, as the strftime is correctly aware of the datetime properties.